# Prove $\Bigg(\langle\nabla f(x),x \rangle = af(x) \Bigg) \Leftrightarrow \Bigg(f(tx)=t^af(x) \Bigg)$ for $f: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ differentiable

Tags: analysis, derivatives, inner-products

Let $n\in \Bbb N , a \in \Bbb R$ and $f: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ differentiable. I have to show:
$$\Bigg(\langle\nabla f(x),x \rangle = af(x) \:\:\:\forall x \in \Bbb R ^n \backslash\{ 0 \} \Bigg) \Leftrightarrow \Bigg(f(tx)=t^af(x) \:\:\:\forall t\gt 0 \textrm{ and }x \in \Bbb R ^n \backslash\{ 0 \} \Bigg)$$

I tried the it with simple functions like $f(x,y,z)=x^3+y^3+z^3$  to convince myself that it works but i don't really know how to prove it.

Any tipps or advice? Thanks in advance

Comment: see here: http://people.hss.caltech.edu/~kcb/Notes/EulerHomogeneity.pdf

Comment: This is called "Euler's Homogeneous Function Theorem", a short proof can be found here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulersHomogeneousFunctionTheorem.html

Comment: I've answered same question in [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1842522/show-relation-and-linearity-related-to-differentiable-functions/1842788#1842788), so you can check it.